# Chord algorithm - how to map nodes to keys?

Tags: algorithms, distributed-systems

I'm trying to understand Chord algorithm (for Peer-to-Peer systems) but I can't understand how it maps the documents to the nodes.

I have one example where we have:

- keys with 4 bits
- 5 active nodes with the following identifiers: 1, 5, 7, 10, 13

After mapping the documents to the nodes, we have:

Key 0 - Node 1

Key 2 - Node 5

Key 8 - Node 10

Key 11 - Node 13

Key 15 - Node 1

If somebody could help me with the steps that lead to this results I'd be truly grateful.

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  What research have you done?  What resources have you read?  Chord is described in a bunch of places.

Answer (score 1):

Chord implementations use a defined function which is used to map the key identifiers (0, 2, 8, 11, 15 in your case) to the node identifiers (1, 5, 7, 10, 13). In the example you provided, the function works like this:

```
NodeID = KeyID % N
```

where **NodeID** is the (identifier) node where the key will be inserted, **KeyID** is the identifier of the key to be inserted, and **N** is the total number of nodes.

After you calculate the **NodeID**, it might be the case that this **NodeID** does not exist. For example, when **KeyID** is 0, the **NodeID** will be 0. Since **NodeID** doesn't exist, it will be allocated to the next highest (existing) node identifier which is **NodeID** = 1.

The keys identifier can be calculated using some hash algorithm.